# Transfering a dynamically allocated matrix in a method of a class in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to make a dynamically allocated bidimensional array with variable size but I don't know why if I create my own constant value it won't compile:

```
    const int oConstanta=N+1;

    int (*m)[oConstanta]=new int[oConstanta][oConstanta];
```

But when I use a normal constant such as 1000 between the brackets it compiles successfully.

```
    const int oConstanta=N+1;

    int (*m)[1000]=new int[1000][1000];
```

Does anyone know the reason for this?

PS: I know that:

```
    int **m=new int*[oConstanta];

    for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
    {
        m[i]=new int[oConstanta];
        init(m[i]);
    }
```

will solve my problems but I want to learn why my former method was a bad idea.

Comment: The first one just isn't standard C++.

Comment: What's the `N`? @smarinov: depending on `N`, yes, it is.

Comment: Don't use pointers. Use an `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead, and preferably write a wrapper class `Matrix`.

Comment: @daknok_t: Ok, but that doesn't teach the OP anything about how this stuff actually works.  End result; programmers who know how to use API's and have no idea how to solve non-trivial problems.

Comment: If `N` is not a constant it usually won't compile.

Comment: @daknok_t: I read some comments about it. And I used vector<> for few years but in this case I don't think is sa good idea. I am using my matrix for the roy-floyd algorithm and using a vector<> means to use O(N^2) if statements that are expensive. Practically I am transforming my adjacency lists into an adjacency matrix.

Comment: @ smarinov   N is not a constant. I want it to be a variable.

Comment: @JaniAlmani Roy-Floyd uses quadratic space and cubic time. A nested `std::vector` won't change the complexity in the slightest since random access still takes constant time.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `N` is a compile-time constant expression, `oConstanta` is not a compile-time constant either.

The best way of making a two-dimensional array in C++ is using `std::vector` of `std::vector`s, for example, like this:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<int> > m(N+1,  std::vector<int>(N+1, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the reason is that you can't create static arrays of variable length.

In your code you are trying to create a static array of dynamic arrays, both of variable length.

Now, static arrays live in the stack, while dynamic arrays live in the heap. While the memory management of the heap is "flexible", the stack is different: the compiler needs to be able to determine the size of each frame in the stack. This is clearly not possible if you use an array of variable length.
On the other hand, if you use a pointer the size of the stack frame is known (a pointer has a known size) and everything is fine.

If you want to try, this should compile fine

```
int (*m)[1000]=new int[oConstanta][1000]
```

since it's a fixed-size static array, whose entries are dynamically allocated arrays of variable length (allowed).

In short: whenever the size of an object is not known at compile time, that object cannot be in the stack, it has to be dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 0):

To make a dynamically sized, 2D matrix with contiguous elements and a single allocation:

```
std::vector<int> matrix(Rows*Columns);
```

Access an element in the *i* th row and *j* th column:

```
matrix[Columns*i + j] = 1;
```

You can wrap this all up in a class. Here's a very basic example:

```
struct Matrix {
    std::vector<int> m;
    size_t rows,columns;

    Matrix(size_t rows,size_t columns)
      : rows(rows)
      , columns(columns)
      , m(rows*columns)
    {}

    int &at(size_t i,size_t j) {
        return m.at(i*columns + j);
    }
};
```